# Custom response message ajax beginform asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ajax.beginform in asp.net mvc 4. In my controller I have a try catch block

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
}
```

in my onFailure event I have

```
function failure(data) {
     $(".progress").hide();
     $.msgGrowl({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'error',
        text: data.statusText
      });
 }
```

the results of data.statusText is "internal server error." In the data.responseText I see that the title tag of the page has the message I'm trying to get. Based on some other suggestions on this site I've changed to

```
var html = data.responseText;
var error = html.find("title");
```

but then I get an error saying that there is no find method.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try `$(html).find("title")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response was helpful but I don't have enough points to mark it as useful. I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but it got me what I needed.

```
function failure(data) {
        $(".progress").hide();
        var html = $(data.responseText);
        var title = $(html)[1];
        var error = $(title).text();
        $.msgGrowl({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'error',
            text: error
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The html in `data.responseText` is just a string. You need to make it a jQuery object in order to use `find()`

Try:

```
var html = $(data.responseText);
```

Comment: This is getting me closer to what I need.

Comment: sorry I hit enter to add a line break and it submitted my comment when I  change to `var html = $(data.responseText); var title = html.find("title");`  in chrome tools it shows title as e.fn.e.init[0] and I can drill down to prevObject the title objects innerhtml and innertext properties have the information I need. When I do `var error = $(title).innerhtml;' it shows up as undefined. How should I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: The `find()` method will give you a jQuery object. To get the text/html, you can simply use `$(data.responseText).text()` or `$(data.responseText).html()` depending on what information you need